# Python print with end option sometimes prints with delay

Tags: python, printing

just like to check if anyone experience the following?

I have a few print statements and one of them has a end='' option.

Example:

```
print('file read completed') 

print('extraction is progress...', end='')
```

This is followed by a nested for loop that takes 19 mins to complete. At the end of the for loop, I printed print('completed')

What I'm experiencing is that after my 1st print of 'file read completed', the next print with end option did not print out. It only prints out after the end of 19 mins together with the 'completed' text.

Between my 1st and 2nd print, there are only some for loops and the loop has exited.

Comment: Add `flush=True` to force render to the console, because without \n it doesn't

Comment: If you want to have a visual feedback of the status of a task made up of a loop of many subtasks, consider to use tqdm. https://tqdm.github.io/  Otherwise use `force=True` can be the right solution

Comment: Thanks. I didnt know print has this option! :-)

Comment: It happened again, even with flush. I tried python - u script.py and it still pause until I press enter. Any other method to stop this?